# gpu decimal precision

Tags: javascript, floating-point, gpu, mandelbrot

I have created a mandelbrot set in javascript which uses the gpu but because javascript decimals are not so accurate when I zoom in to much the screen goes pixely. If i were programing it on the cpu it would not be so hard but because I am using gpu.js I cant use strings and therefore no decimal libraries I know.

I only want to increase the accuracy, not make it endless.

Is there any way to create a more precise float with multiple floats (I can not use strings because of the library's limitation) so that I can:

- multiply
- add
- use powers

[image of the pixlation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezaR6.png)

Comment: Is there any reason you specifically need **decimal**?  Can you rely on the underlying binary floating-point that your CPU/GPU provides?

Comment: You don't need strings for arbitrary precision work.  Arrays should do fine.

Comment: that should be good. It will take time to create the function but I think it is still the best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

googling : gpu and "arbitrary precision" shows IMHO that this problem is not solved now.

So you can:

- write your own library
- use CPU arbitrary precision libraries